# How to make the Anchor tag <a> scale by hovering on it?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to scale the `<a href="#">anchor tag</a>` by using

```
a:hover {  transform: scale(1.5) }
```

Just like I use `h1:hover{ transform: scale(1.5); }` to scale the heading.
But it's not working, the anchor tag doesn't scale.

Comment: Please share some code to help others reproduce the issue. [You can use Stack Snippets to help!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `display:inline-block` property unlike `display:inline` then you can scale the element.
HTML:
`<a href="www.google.com">Go To Google</a>`

CSS

```
a:hover{
  display:inline-block;
  -ms-transform: scale(5.5, 5.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(5.5, 5.5); /* Safari */
    transform: scale(5.5, 5.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the browser prefix:

```css
a:hover 
{  
   -ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5); /* Safari */
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">anchor tag</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scale doesn't work on inline elements, set a `display: inline-block;` for the anchor tag, that should work.

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Let me know if that helps you!

Comment: Great! Glad to help!