# Hover: scale does not work with TailwindCSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I want the email to pop out a bit so it is visible that you are on it. I am trying to use the hover class from Tailwind but somehow there is no effect on it.

My project is React with NextJS framework.

```
import React from "react";
const currentDate = new Date().getFullYear();
import packageFile from "@/../package.json";

function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer className="flex justify-center py-[8px]">
      <p className="text-gray-500 text-[10px]">
        {currentDate} © website.com /{" "}
        <a href="mailto:test@email.com" className="text-sky-500 hover:scale-150">test@email.com</a> / v{""}
        <span>{packageFile.version}</span>
      </p>
    </footer>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

Comment: You could add "inline-block" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267000/how-to-make-the-anchor-tag-a-scale-by-hovering-on-it

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution did not work for me. I also tried other forms of displays.